# What is Big-O runtime of the standard random number generator in python? (Worst-case)

Tags: python, algorithm, random, big-o

Sample python2 code:

```
for i in range(N):
    print str(random.randint(0, N))
```

Is it safe to assume that the random number generator runs in O(1), so that the above loop (which simply prints N random numbers in the range from 0 - N) is O(N) ?

Comment: Python uses [MT19937](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-MAT/MT/ARTICLES/mt.pdf) (Mersenne Twister). It runs pretty much in constant time. But `randint()` uses [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) with an average of `[2^floor(log N)]/N` samples.

Comment: Correction: an average of `[2^ceil(log N)]/N` trials.

Comment: O-notation is a meaningless way to measure PRNGs. *Every* PRNG is O(n) in the number of bits generated. I am not aware of any exceptions--even BlumBlumShub, which is deadly slow, is O(n) with a big constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.randint(0, N)` is probably `O(log N)` i.e., it is proportional to number of bits in `N`.

[The implementation confirms it](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py#l220) if we assume that `.getrandbits(k)` is `O(k)`.

[It seems to be true for CPython](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/_randommodule.c#l349) if `genrand_int32()` is `O(1)`. [The source (for Mersenne Twister PRNG implementation) suggests that it is](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/_randommodule.c#l93).

Comment: `getrandbits(k)` is O(1) for `k <= 32`. `_randbelow()` uses rejection sampling, therefore it needs an average of `[2^floor(log2 N)]/N` samples, but the actual value could fluctuate.

Comment: `k <= 32` behavior has no effect on Big-O. The coefficient is `O(1)`: `[2^floor(log N)]/N` ~ `2**floor(log N) / 2**(log N)` -> `2**(floor(x) - x)` -> `1`.

Comment: For N that is not a power of 2 the average sample count is in [1, 2). And if one is unlucky, it could take way more than 2 trials until `getrandbits()` returns a value less than N. Honestly, I have no idea how to express a random number of steps in a Big-O notation.

Comment: If it is not clear; the constant factor is ignored in the above calculations (`O(1)`). The point is that however many trials it would require, the number does not depends on `N` (it is `O(1)` with probability `1`).

Answer (score 0):

I have also very long wonder what could be the complexity of generating random numbers and it is not easy to find the answer on the internet.

I carried out my own experiment (the code ran in roughly 9min on my laptop intel vPRO i9 + 32Go RAM). Here are the results:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm

sizes = np.geomspace(1,1e9,100)

# instantiate resuls lists
list_times_create_random_array = []
list_times_compute_mean = []
list_times_compute_sqared_values = []
list_times_loop = []

# run benchmark
for size in tqdm(sizes):
    # create a random generator to be sure the next step focuses on generation only
    rng = np.random.default_rng(datetime.now().microsecond)
    # step 1: generation
    t1 = datetime.now()
    arr = rng.uniform(0,1,int(size))
    # step 2: compute mean
    t2 = datetime.now()
    np.mean(arr)
    # step 2: compute squared array
    t3 = datetime.now()
    arr**2
    # step 4: loop on array without variable asignment
    t4 = datetime.now()
    for _ in arr:
        continue
    t5 = datetime.now()

    list_times_create_random_array.append((t2-t1).seconds*1000000+(t2-t1).microseconds)
    list_times_compute_mean.append((t3-t2).seconds*1000000+(t3-t2).microseconds)
    list_times_compute_sqared_values.append((t4-t3).seconds*1000000+(t4-t3).microseconds)
    list_times_loop.append((t5-t4).seconds*1000000+(t5-t4).microseconds)

plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_array,label='create random array')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_compute_mean,label='compute mean')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_compute_sqared_values,label='compute squared array')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_loop,label='loop on array')
plt.xlabel('sizes of array')
plt.ylabel('time (µs)')
plt.legend()

plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_array)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio create random array over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_compute_sqared_values)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio compute squared array over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_loop)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio loop on array over mean')
plt.xlabel('sizes of array')
plt.ylabel('how many time slower than mean')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.hlines(y=50,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='green')
plt.text(s=50,x=-1.1e8,y=50)
plt.hlines(y=4.5,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='blue')
plt.text(s=4.5,x=-1.1e8,y=4.5)
plt.hlines(y=1.5,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='orange')
plt.text(s=1.5,x=-1.1e8,y=1.5)
plt.legend()
```

Here is the evolution of the computation time in microseconds for the 4 operations "mean", "square", "for loop" and "random number generation".

[image]

And see below the evolution of these computational time normalized by the time of the "mean" operation. On can see that assuming that the mean operation is said to be "1 time unit", then the squared operation is 1.5, the random generation is 4.5 and the for loop is 50.

[image]